# Is there a way to write (reasoning/explanation) after each line in align?

Tags: align

So if I use align to have a series of equations proving a statement, is there a way that I can have an explanation inside parentheses, on the far right?

Something like:

1. a | b              (hypothesis)
2. b | c              (hypothesis)
3. a | c              (1,2, Trans)

But with a lot more space between the formulas and the (explanation)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Are the 1,2,3 equation numbers or merely local step numbers?  If so, are they to be on the left?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to write latex directly on the website, I was trying to emulate the latex align

Comment: My question stands...does each line have its own equation number in the overall scheme of the paper, or are the numbers merely local steps in the [numberless] proof?

Answer (score 2):

The OP leaves much unsaid, so I will assume.  I assume that I am looking at something that I will call a "proof."   I assume the numbers to the left are step numbers in the proof, and not individual referenceable equation numbers.  I assume the overall "proof" is unnumbered.

I use `tabstackengine` to set up an `align` structure.  What this package gives you is the ability to define the gap between adjacent elements in the structure.

I chose to make the stack in text mode and set off the math inline.  Alternately, one could declare `\TABstackMath`, and set off the text as `\textrm{}` or (with `amsmath`) as `\text`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackText
\begin{document}
\[
\alignCenterstack{
 1.&& $a\vert$& $b$ &&(hypothesis)\\
 2.&& $b\vert$& $c$ &&(hypothesis)\\
 3.&& $a\vert$& $c$ &&(1,2 Trans)
}
\]
\[
\setstackaligngap{3em}
\alignCenterstack{
 1.&& $a\vert$& $b$ &&(hypothesis)\\
 2.&& $b\vert$& $c$ &&(hypothesis)\\
 3.&& $a\vert$& $c$ &&(1,2 Trans)
}
\]
\[
\setstackaligngap{1em}
\alignCenterstack{
 1.&& $a\vert$& $b$ &&&&(hypothesis)\\
 2.&& $b\vert$& $c$ &&&&(hypothesis)\\
 3.&& $a\vert$& $c$ &&&&(1,2 Trans)
}
\]
\[
\setstackaligngap{1ex}
\alignCenterstack{
 1.&& $a\vert$& $b$ &\kern50pt&(hypothesis)\\
 2.&& $b\vert$& $c$ &&(hypothesis)\\
 3.&& $a\vert$& $c$ &&(1,2 Trans)
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]